# WPF LiveCharts MVVM C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, serialport, livechart

Пишу программу , которая считывает значение с датчика и записывает его как точку графика. Моя проблема в том что график не обновляется. Общение с датчиком происходит через `SerialPort` и точку я хочу доставать из события по приёму `DataReceived`. Для графика использую **LiveCharts**.

Строить пытаюсь через `ChartValues<ObservableValues> MyValues` в который добавляю значение путём `MyValues.Add(new ObservableValue(значение))`, но оно не обновляет график через свойство в **ViewModel**.

Xaml разметка для графика :

```xml
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
            Fully Responsive
        </TextBlock>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 0 10 0">Points</TextBlock>
            <Button Command="{Binding DrawPointCommand,Mode=OneWay}" >+</Button>
            <Button>/</Button>
            <Button>-</Button>
            <Button >MoveAll</Button>
            <TextBlock Margin="0 0 10 0" VerticalAlignment="Center">Series</TextBlock>
            <Button>+</Button>
            <Button>-</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <lvc:CartesianChart Grid.Row="2" LegendLocation="Right">
            <lvc:CartesianChart LegendLocation="Right">
                <lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
                    <lvc:LineSeries PointGeometry="{x:Null}" Fill="Transparent"
                            StrokeThickness="3" Title="0xC0"
                            Values="{Binding MyValues , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <lvc:LineSeries PointGeometry="{x:Null}" Fill="Transparent"
                            StrokeThickness="3" Title="0xC1"
                            Values="{Binding SPoints}" />
                </lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
            </lvc:CartesianChart>
        </lvc:CartesianChart>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Пока что попытался сделать через кнопку с командой `DrawPointCommand`,которая цепляет температуру из датчика. Кнопка вечно рисует нулевое значение.

Метод подписанный на `DrawPointCommand`:

```cs
private void DrawPoint()
{
    MyValues.Add(new ObservableValue(_monitoringblock.Temperature));
}
```

Часть конструктора которая относится к графикам :

```cs
MyValues = new ChartValues<ObservableValue>
{
    new ObservableValue(5), new ObservableValue(7), new ObservableValue(8), new ObservableValue(3)
};
var lineSeries = new LineSeries 
{
    Values = MyValues, StrokeThickness = 4, Fill = Brushes.Transparent, PointGeometrySize = 0, DataLabels = false
};
SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection { lineSeries };
```

Свойство MyValues:

```cs
public ChartValues<ObservableValue> MyValues
{
    get
    {
        return _myvalue;
    }
    set
    {
        _myvalue = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyValues));
    }
}
```

В отладке по нажатию кнопки изменяется количество элементов,но судя по графику это всё нули. Через принятые от датчика данные не рисуются даже нули.

Так выглядит событие приема по порту :

```cs
private void dataReceived(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _myvalue.Add(new ObservableValue(MonitoringViewModel.Concentration));
    OnPropertyChanged("MyValues");
}
```

Внутри самого приложения данные по приёму обновляются нормально.
Копал в отладке.

[image: Копал в отладке.Получается что в данном случае OnPropertyChanged() не работает?]

Получается `OnPropertyChanged()` работает неправильно? Просто дело в том, что он справлялся до этого и всё обновлял правильно.Точнее даже обновляет всё,кроме графика.

Comment: `MyValues = new ChartValues<ObservableValue>` - вангую, что подобные свойства у вас без INPC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело было в **DataContext**. Если точнее то **UserControl** который отображается в основном окне не должен его иметь. Так же свойство `MyValues` дополнительно должно обновиться при помощи `NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True`.